# Sort a list based on index of another list values

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am trying to use a comparator to sort my List 2 based on List 1.

So the two lists are:

```
ListA = [2,3,4]
ListB = [8,2,4]
```

I need to sort list 2 based on list 1.

Expected output:

```
List1: [2,3,4]
List2: [2,8,4]
```

Here is the code I am trying

```
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2,new Comparator<Integer>(){
    public int compare(Integer left,Integer right){
        return Integer.compare(list1.indexOf(left),list1.indexOf(right));
    }
})
```

Here sorting will be based on index of List1 elements. The comparator above is not working for me Please help?

Comment: Yes thats a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected it.

Comment: 8 is not in List1, how to do then?

Comment: And what do you mean by "Not working"? What is your output?

Comment: You need to decide on a case when a number is not in a List1 (like 8), it's not clear from your example what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: BTW the code doesn't really make any sense as you are sorting list 1 first. Why would you do that?

Comment: @MarkKeen I think you missed the point. He is trying to sort according to the index of the elements in the first list, which means is L1 = {3, 2, 4}, then if you take L2 = {2, 3, 4} it will get sorted as {3, 2, 4}

Comment: @realUser404 Exactly, that is the point. I am not able to think a code that will work for this condition. Trying from last 3 hours.

Comment: In order to help the very least we need is a clear description of your requirements. What is the output of your code? And in what way is it different from the expected output?

Comment: Does it even compile? list1 in not in the scope of your comparator.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me from your example what you're trying to do, so this answer might not actually address your question. If what you're trying to do is to apply the sort-order of ListA to both ListA and ListB then you can do it as follows.

Create an auxiliary class that allows you to pair up the two lists with respect to the same index:

```java
private class IntPair implements Comparable<IntPair> {
    int i1;
    int i2;

    public IntPair(int i1, int i2) {
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }

    public int compareTo(IntPair other) {
        return Integer.compare(i1, other.i1);
    }
}
```

Then create a new list of `IntPair` instances from your original lists and sort it.

```java
int size = list1.size();
List<IntPair> aux = new ArrayList(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    aux.add(new IntPair(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)))
}

Collections.sort(aux);
```

Finally, copy back the values of the resulting pair list onto your original lists.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    IntPair ip = aux.get(i);
    list1.set(i, ip.i1);
    list2.set(i, ip.i2);
}
```

Note that in terms of algorithmic complexity, this approach still is `O(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little heavy-weight, but it gets the job done and it's generic.

Essentially, you can zip-up two lists, sort/compare them based off an index, unzip them, and return the result.

This does not modify the list in-place. I tried to give the variables meaningful, but discreet names. Please acknowledge me for clarification.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> indicies = Arrays.asList(3, 2, 4);
        List<Integer> values   = Arrays.asList(8, 2, 4);
        List<Integer> sorted   = doSort(indicies, values, new TupleComparator<Integer>(0, 1) {
            @Override
            public int doCompare(Integer valueA, Integer valueB) {
                return Integer.compare(valueA, valueB);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(sorted); // [2, 8, 4]
    }

    public static List<Integer> doSort(List<Integer> listA, List<Integer> listB, TupleComparator<Integer> comparator) {
        List<Tuple<Integer>> tuples = zip(listA, listB);
        Collections.sort(tuples, comparator);
        return unzip(tuples, comparator.getValuePos());
    }

    private static <E> List<E> unzip(List<Tuple<E>> tuples, int index) {
        List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (Tuple<E> tuple : tuples) {
            list.add(tuple.getData().get(index));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static <E> List<Tuple<E>> zip(List<E> listA, List<E> listB) {
        List<Tuple<E>> listC = new ArrayList<Tuple<E>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
            listC.add(new Tuple<E>(Arrays.asList(listA.get(i), listB.get(i))));
        }
        return listC;
    }

    private static abstract class TupleComparator<E> implements Comparator<Tuple<E>> {
        private int indexPos;
        private int valuePos;
        public TupleComparator(int indexPos, int valuePos) {
            this.indexPos = indexPos;
            this.valuePos = valuePos;
        }
        public int compare(Tuple<E> left, Tuple<E> right) {
            E indexA = left.getData().get(this.getIndexPos());
            E indexB = right.getData().get(this.getIndexPos());
            return doCompare(indexA,  indexB);
        }
        public int getIndexPos() { return indexPos; }
        public int getValuePos() { return valuePos; }
        public abstract int doCompare(E valueA, E valueB);
    }

    private static class Tuple<T> {
        private List<T> data;
        public Tuple(List<T> data) { this.data = data; }
        public List<T> getData() {return data; }
    }
}
```